# Как написать условие на php, не выводить строчку, если переменная пустая?

Tags: php

Как не выводить строчку (ссылку), если переменная 'marquee' пустая? В переменную будет записываться значение из инпута. Если не заполнено, то ссылку не выводим.

```
<a href="<?php get_theme_mod('marquee')?>">
<img src="/img/social/instagram.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Здесь нигде нет переменной. Переменная выглядит так - `$marquee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему требуется что-то такое:

```
<?php
$marquee = get_theme_mod('marquee');
if ($marquee) {?>
    <a href="<?php echo $marquee;?>">
        <img src="/img/social/instagram.png">
    </a>
<?php
}
```